# Joining three datagridview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]i want to join three datagrid values in one grid.iam getting the output(see image).But i want that amount in first row.if some value occupy in one row another datagridvalue is not in same row..i need all in same row

Below My Code.check it out..please help me to rectify it.

```
 da4 = New SqlDataAdapter("Select scanamount ,othersamount  FROM scana  where billdate='" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "'", con)
    da4.Fill(ds2)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)

    da2 = New SqlDataAdapter("Select amount as LABAMOUNT  FROM labentry  where billdate='" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "'", con)
    da2.Fill(ds6)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds6.Tables(0)
    ds6.Merge(ds2)

    da5 = New SqlDataAdapter("Select pid as PID,patientname AS PATIENTNAME FROM opentry where date='" + DateTimePicker1.Text + "'", con)
    da5.Fill(ds4)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds4.Tables(0)
    ds4.Merge(ds6)

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds4.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Comment: Your image is not here and the question is not 100% clear but I can guess that you want data from three queries to show in one row on one grid.  If the tables are all in one database, I suggest you JOIN the data in the SQL query and get everything for one grid in one SELECT statement.  To do that you need to know what fields link the data between SCANA, LABENTRY, and OPENTRY.

Comment: sorry..now i uploaded the image.the FIELDNAME is" patientname"..and my doubt is can you give the code of SELECT query to JOIN three tables.

Comment: Hi....i got that query..In My output the patient may get labamount and scan amount.so i dont know how to join.my query "Select distinct scana.scanamount ,scana.othersamount ,labentry.amount ,opentry.pid ,opentry.patientnameFROM scana JOIN labentry ON (scana.PID = labentry.PID) JOIN opentry ON (scana.PID = opentry.PID)  where opentry.billdate='09/11/2017'"